# Linq to SQL Not Logging?

Tags: linq-to-sql, logging

Using Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4 as a Console App.

With a breakpoint on the close of the using statement, Visual Studio shows the select statement when hovering over "stuff". However, "stmt1" and "stmt2" are both empty. Why?

Thanks.

Console app:

```
using ( var cona = new mydbcontext(connstring) )
    {
        var stuff = from a in cona.testtable select a;
        var stmt1 = cona.SqlStatement;
        string stmt2 = cona.GetLoggedInformation();
    }
```

and

```
public partial class mydbcontext : DataContext
{
    private StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        this.CommandTimeout = 120;
        this.Log = new StringWriter(bldr);
    }
    public String GetLoggedInformation()
    {
        return bldr.ToString();
    }
    public string SqlStatement
    {
        get { return this.bldr.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the log is not written until the statement is executed.

Try this

```
using ( var cona = new mydbcontext(connstring) )
{
    var stuff = from a in cona.testtable select a;
    var data = stuff.ToList();
    var stmt1 = cona.SqlStatement;
    string stmt2 = cona.GetLoggedInformation();
}
```

Comment: That was it. I wasn't being patient enough. Once I had "stuff.ToList()" the stmt1 was populated. Thanks!

Comment: I am curious though why in my original code, hovering over stuff showed the sql statement; it's like Visual Studio knows something the trace/string writer doesn't know.